# Image of gauss map

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

Let $M$ be a compact oriented regular surface with smooth unit normal vector
field $N$.
Let $P =\{p\in M| K(p)\geq 0\},$ where $K$ is the Gaussian curvature.
Prove that $N(P)$, the image of $P$ under Gauss map, is the unit sphere $\mathbb{S}^2$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: For all $p \in \mathbb S^2$, let $L_p$ be a two plane which is perpendicular to $p$. Translate this plane to that it touches your surface at only one point $x\in M$.

Comment: I understand the idea but how can I write it down.

Comment: If you understand that, I suggest that you at least try to write it down (for example, in your question) once. That would be good for you and also I can see clearly where you have problem with. @user134927